# Can't run Flask-SocketIO on multiple files layout

Tags: python, flask-socketio, python-socketio

I can't figure out how to `run` `socketio` instead of `app`.
I solved the problem in a ptoject, which was using Blueprint scheme:

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app().socketio
```

But now I have another files configuration.

Project layout:

```
-
|- app
|   |- __init__.py
|   |- routes.py
|- venv
|- my_app.py
```

routes.py

```
# ...
from app import app, socketio
# ...
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)

socketio = SocketIO(app)

from app import routes
```

-OR-

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)

socketio = SocketIO()
socketio.init_app(app)

with app.app_context():
    app.socketio = socketio

from app import routes
```

my_app.py

```
from app import app

app = app.socketio
```

-OR-

```
from app import socketio as app
```

-OR-

```
from app import app, socketio

app = socketio
```

terminal

```
flask --app my_app run
flask --app my_app:socketio run
```

But answers to my attemptions were like these:

```
Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module 'my_app'. 
Error: A valid Flask application was not obtained from 'my_app:socketio'.
```

How can I `socketio.run()` from terminal?
Thanka.

Comment: You are trying to run the application with the `flask` command, which is not supported by Flask-SocketIO. Put the `socketio.run()` call in your main Python script, then execute that script, for example: `python my_script.py`.